# Noisy ducts, problem with insulation?

Tags: hvac, insulation, attic, ducts, noise-reduction

I have what I'm coming to believe is a unique noise issue with the HVAC ducting in my house. I've spoken to four different professionals and they are all somewhat dumbfounded.

The problem is that my ducting makes a significant amount of small pop noises for about 30 minutes while the furnace first turns on and for about 30 minutes after the furnace turns off. I have determined it is not coming from the furnace itself but instead is a result of the ducting expanding and contracting from the heat.

I was thinking that the ducting was rubbing against the wood framing of the house, however, I went in the attic today to observe and now believe the noise may be due to how the ducting is insulated. The ducting appears to have two layers of insulation and the outer layer has a paper backing on it and is held to the ducting with string. The sound that I'm hearing in the house is an amplified version of what it sounds like when that paper backing is pressed on, making me think that the string and paper backing are somehow flexing and the ducting is amplifying the sound.

Judging by the shape of the insulation, I'm thinking it may need to be re-insulated anyway. You can see how the string has broken in some of the pictures causing the insulation to fall off of the duct.

Has anyone ever heard of this before? I'm planning on blowing in additional insulation soon and am wondering what I can do to fix the sound issue and also repair this insulation, if needed.

[image: String and paper backed insulation]

[image: Insulation failure]

Comment: Almost all metal ducts make noise as they are heated. If the string is really tight that may amplify the problem. Duct tape will hold the insulation in place without adding adding stress to the pipe and may reduce the amount of noise but there will always be some with long runs of metal ducts.

Comment: I agree that the issue is normal expansion and contractions, perhaps you've never had old ductwork before now?  Newer doesn't seem to be as prone to the popping...

Comment: Yes, perhaps I'm not used to it. It's too bad it's loud enough to wake us up in the house in the morning. Does it look like it needs to be re-insulated, and, would re-insulating solve the sound problem?